# How to sort a div using 2(!) data-attributes?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, sorting

I want to sort the div using 2 data-attributes. I use this code

```
<div class='fff' data-player="77" data-revision="0">Oxlade</div>
<div class="fff" data-player="85" data-revision="0">Draxler</div>
<div class="fff" data-player="80" data-revision="4">Kamara</div>
```

I tryed this script:

```
var divList = $(".fff");
divList.sort(function(a, b){ return $(b).data("player") $(a).data("player")});
divList.sort(function(a, b){ return $(b).data("revision") $(a).data("revision")});

$("#spelerss").html(divList);
```

But it only sorts on data-player and not data-revision ?!
So first he has to sort the revision,
Kamara should be first after the sort because his 'revision' is higher than the others, following by Draxler because he is higher than Oxlade and as last Oxlade

Comment: While we *can* do this for you, that's not what this site is about; you should post your own attempted solution, explain where it went wrong (and *how* it went wrong), and where you're stuck. We're *not* here to do your work *for* you, but to help you address and resolve problems with your code.

Comment: @DavidThomas done, can you help now?

Comment: I'm too lazy to post some code, but I'd suggest the sort logic of comparing `a.data-player` and `b.data-player` (subtracting them since they're both numbers), then before returning a positive number, negative number, or 0, check if you will be returning 0. If you will be returning 0, then compare `a.data-revision` with `b.data-revision`. If you need to reverse the order of either, multiply by `-1` and it will invert the sorting order for whichever field you're sorting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Mohamed-Yousef mentioned you can just use the `.sort()` capabilities, but the logic in the other answers is a bit off.

The call should look like...

```
$('.fff').sort(function (a, b) {
         return  ($(b).data('revision')+ "" + $(b).data('player')) - ($(a).data('revision')+ "" + $(a).data('player'));
    }).appendTo('body');
```

This is due to the fact that doing one sort FOLLOWED by another just runs a new sort. You need to do some sort of concatenation in order for the sort to function correctly.

[Working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/n7pxefo5/4/)

Answer (score 0):

you can use .sort()

```
$('.fff').sort(function (a, b) {
    return parseInt($(b).attr('data-player')) - parseInt($(a).attr('data-player'));
}).appendTo('body');
```

[**Working Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/mohamedyousef1980/n7pxefo5/)

> Note: This code will sort from higher data-player to lower data-player

next code will sort by data-revision

```
$('.fff').sort(function (a, b) {
   return parseInt($(b).attr('data-revision')) - parseInt($(a).attr('data-revision'));
}).appendTo('body');
```

[**Working Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/mohamedyousef1980/n7pxefo5/2/)

for sorting twice *(after question update)*

```
    $(".fff").sort(function (a, b) {return parseInt($(b).attr('data-player')) - parseInt($(a).attr('data-player'));
    }).sort(function (a, b) {
             return parseInt($(b).attr('data-revision')) - parseInt($(a).attr('data-revision'));
    }).appendTo('body');
```

[**Working Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/mohamedyousef1980/n7pxefo5/3/)

Comment: yes but that will only sort the "data-player"

Comment: How can I first sort by revision and then by data revision?

Comment: @J.terWeele updated answer??